# Break equation with \left( and \right) doesn't work exactly while using classicthesis

Tags: equations, classicthesis, split

Compiling the following MWE produces different bracket [] heights by using `\usepackage{classicthesis}`. If this package is commented out, the equation is correct. What does the package load, that it fails? Or is there another way to write this equation?

Thank you!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \Bigg( \Bigg.& \left[ - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_\mathrm{e}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_\mathrm{e}} + V_\mathrm{e}(z_\mathrm{e}) \right] + \left[ - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_\mathrm{h}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_\mathrm{h}} + V_\mathrm{h}(z_\mathrm{h}) \right] - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0m_\mathrm{eh}} \nabla^2 \\
        & - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r \sqrt{\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2+(z_\mathrm{e}-z_\mathrm{h})^2}} \Bigg. \Bigg) \psi_\mathrm{ex} (\mathbf{r},z_\mathrm{e},z_\mathrm{h}) = E \, \psi_\mathrm{ex} (\mathbf{r},z_\mathrm{e},z_\mathrm{h})
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There actually is a difference in the input that could cause larger brackets, and that is the subscript "h", vs. "e".  This could be adjusted by using `\smash{\mathrm{h}}` to eliminate the height/depth difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\left`/`\right` automatically size the brackets to fit the inner formula, so if you pass formulas of different height to them you can't expect to get the same size of brackets. Use explicit sizes using e.g. `\biggl` / `\biggr` instead if you want consistent sizes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      \Biggl( & \biggl[ - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_\mathrm{e}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_\mathrm{e}} + V_\mathrm{e}(z_\mathrm{e}) \biggr] + \biggl[ - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_\mathrm{h}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_\mathrm{h}} + V_\mathrm{h}(z_\mathrm{h}) \biggr] - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0m_\mathrm{eh}} \nabla^2 \\
        & - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r \sqrt{\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2+(z_\mathrm{e}-z_\mathrm{h})^2}} \Biggr) \psi_\mathrm{ex} (\mathbf{r},z_\mathrm{e},z_\mathrm{h}) = E \, \psi_\mathrm{ex} (\mathbf{r},z_\mathrm{e},z_\mathrm{h})
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Besides using fixed height delimiters, that is, `\bigl` `\bigr` and friends (but never `\big` without the `l` or `r` specification), I recommend not using `scrartcl` with `classicthesis`.

When the package was born, it recommended KOMA classes, but nowadays you get loads of warnings and in the future LaTeX runs may even fail.

Beware that `_\mathrm{e}` is syntactically wrong, even if it seems to work (it may not in general). I suggest also adding a semantic command, here `\tsb` for “*t*extual *s*u*b*script).

You may also use NewPX instead of `mathpazo` (more modern and with larger symbol supply).

I provide three versions; I'd prefer the first one, because there is no need to cover entirely the material.

If you think that the parenthesis is too near to the following material, use `\,` and not `\Bigg.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <-- no longer necessary
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\newcommand{\tsb}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \biggl(
      & \Bigl[
          - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_{\tsb{e}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_{\tsb{e}}}
          + V_{\tsb{e}}(z_{\tsb{e}})
        \Bigr] 
      + \Bigl[
          - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_{\tsb{h}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_{\tsb{h}}}
          + V_{\tsb{h}}(z_{\tsb{h}})
        \Bigr]
      - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0m_{\tsb{eh}}} \nabla^2
      \\
      & - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r 
                     \sqrt{\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2+(z_{\tsb{e}}-z_{\tsb{h}})^2}}
   \biggr) \psi_{\tsb{ex}} (\mathbf{r},z_{\tsb{e}},z_{\tsb{h}})
   = E \, \psi_{\tsb{ex}} (\mathbf{r},z_{\tsb{e}},z_{\tsb{h}})
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \biggl(
      & \biggl[
          - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_{\tsb{e}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_{\tsb{e}}}
          + V_{\tsb{e}}(z_{\tsb{e}})
        \biggr] 
      + \biggl[
          - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_{\tsb{h}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_{\tsb{h}}}
          + V_{\tsb{h}}(z_{\tsb{h}})
        \biggr]
      - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0m_{\tsb{eh}}} \nabla^2
      \\
      & - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r 
                     \sqrt{\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2+(z_{\tsb{e}}-z_{\tsb{h}})^2}}
   \biggr) \psi_{\tsb{ex}} (\mathbf{r},z_{\tsb{e}},z_{\tsb{h}})
   = E \, \psi_{\tsb{ex}} (\mathbf{r},z_{\tsb{e}},z_{\tsb{h}})
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \Biggl(
      & \biggl[
          - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_{\tsb{e}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_{\tsb{e}}}
          + V_{\tsb{e}}(z_{\tsb{e}})
        \biggr] 
      + \biggl[
          - \frac{\hbar}{2m_0m_{\tsb{h}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2_{\tsb{h}}}
          + V_{\tsb{h}}(z_{\tsb{h}})
        \biggr]
      - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0m_{\tsb{eh}}} \nabla^2
      \\
      & - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r 
                     \sqrt{\lvert \mathbf{r} \rvert^2+(z_{\tsb{e}}-z_{\tsb{h}})^2}}
   \Biggr) \psi_{\tsb{ex}} (\mathbf{r},z_{\tsb{e}},z_{\tsb{h}})
   = E \, \psi_{\tsb{ex}} (\mathbf{r},z_{\tsb{e}},z_{\tsb{h}})
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the version without NewPX.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest employing a `multline` environment instead of an `equation/split` setup. I would also employ an upright letter "E" to denote the expectations operator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % {scrartcl}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\ze{z_{\mathrm{e}}}
\newcommand\zh{z_{\mathrm{h}}}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{newpxtext} \useosf
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\biggl( 
  \biggl[ -\frac{\hbar}{2m_0 m_{\mathrm{e}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \ze^2} 
     + V_{\mathrm{e}}(\ze) \biggr] 
+ \biggl[ -\frac{\hbar}{2m_0 m_{\mathrm{h}}} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \zh^2} 
     + V_{\mathrm{h}}(\zh) \biggr] 
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_0 m_{\mathrm{eh}}} \nabla^2 \\
- \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r \sqrt{\abs{\mathbf{r}}^2
  +(\ze-\zh)^2}} \biggr) \, \psi_{\mathrm{ex}} (\mathbf{r},\ze,\zh) 
= \E \psi_{\mathrm{ex}} (\mathbf{r},\ze,\zh)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why should the expactations operator be upright? In the literature it is always be italic.

Comment: @nico.wagner - I guess it depends on the literature, then. I'm an econometrician, and in the econometrics literature the expectations operator is mostly (though admittedly not uniformly) written either as `\mathrm{E}` or even `\mathbb{E}` (which, incidentally, also employs an upright letter). Note that by defining `\E` to be of TeX category `math-op`, it's also not necessary to insert a thin space manually -- as you saw fit to do (correctly!, IMNSHO) in your code -- after the letter.

Comment: The expectations operator in the Schrödinger equation is the Energy operator, so that is most probably the case why it should be written italic in physics literatures. But I agree with you, the multline environment is the better option. Thanks!